# how to get last oredered same value and eliminating some values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id  ||   user_id   ||  value
==============================
1   ||   1         ||  2
2   ||   1         ||  4
3   ||   2         ||  6
4   ||   3         ||  2
5   ||   4         ||  ex
6   ||   1         ||  2
7   ||   1         ||  ex
8   ||   1         ||  4
```

In this table, I need to get last ordered same user_id =1, And eliminate ex in value column. So my table is like below.

```
id  ||   user_id   ||  value
==============================
6   ||  1          ||  2  
8   ||  1          ||  4
```

Comment: which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: phpmyadmin Version information: 5.0.1, latest stable version: 4.9.5

Comment: Why do 2,6 and 3,2 not appear in your desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your requirement correct or not, but if I am close, you can try this below logic for achieving your requirement-

> You need latest version of MySQL where ROW_NUMBER and CTE is supported

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) new_id
    FROM your_table A
    WHERE A.value <> 'ex'
)

SELECT A.id,A.user_id,A.value
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT MAX(C.new_id) new_id 
    FROM CTE C
    LEFT JOIN CTE D 
        ON C.new_id-1 = D.new_id
    WHERE C.user_id = D.user_id
    ORDER BY C.new_id
)B ON A.new_id = B.new_id OR A.new_id+1 = B.new_id
```

You can check the [Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8cce997b9ea90f2ca6e735fecdd61ece)

Answer (score 1):

I can interpret this question as getting the last value for user_id = 1 *between* the ``` ex`` values.  If so, you can use window functions.  One does a cumulative sum of ``` 'ex'`.  The other gets the row you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ex_grp, user_id order by id desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*, sum(value = 'ex') over (order by id) as ex_grp
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where user_id = 1 and seqnum = 1
```

Comment: its worked but it is also eliminating the same value with 'ex'. The user_id when have same 2 records, Example two or more six 6, its just get one six and eliminating others.